# Kotlin coroutine - Type mismatch when trying to return ArrayList from a suspended function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a suspended method which is expected to return an ArrayList. However, on trying to do that the IDE highlights a type mismatch error within the coroutine scope.

My method -

```
private suspend fun dbsearchHelper(query: String): ArrayList<String> {

    return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        if (query.length > 3) {
            return@withContext SupportedPackagesManager.findStoreByName(query)
        }
    }
}
```

Error -

```
Type interference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String>
found: Any!
```

The `findStoreByName` is a Java method.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: That's because you don't have an else option in your withContext. There's a case where your withContext returns Unit (when query.length <= 3).

Comment: @the_dani Thanks. The error was not self-explanatory at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an else branch so Kotlin can explicitly know what you do return.

In your case, Kotlin takes sets the return type of withContext to Any, since if (query.length <= 3), your withContext returns Unit.